# Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'CentrixMOS.SongsActivity' via nested type 'CentrixMOS.SongsActivity.importDeals'

Tags: xamarin.android

I have an error stated above,, how can i call a function from another class, I'm using xamarin in mono for android,,.. is there anyone who is expert in using mono for android.,,?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens probably because you are trying to convert Java code to C#.

Xamarin has a nice article about this. Take a look at [API design](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/api_design), especially section 4.5. Here is an excerpt from that article.

> Non-static nested classes, also called inner classes, are significantly different. They contain an implicit reference to an instance of their enclosing type and cannot contain static members (among other differences outside the scope of this overview).

So, you should pass a reference of `CentrixMOS.SongsActivity` to `CentrixMOS.SongsActivity.importDeals` then access the members of it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply ..  I am all new in android. I am web developer .,,